# Content not loading properly slick js

Tags: slick.js

My content in slick is not loading properly. However, if I click or change the window size of the browser it works fine. How can I fix the same?

I have added the below CSS but still not working.

```
.slider-container {
overflow: hidden;
}

.slick-slide: nth-of-child(n+1) {
display: none;
}

.slick-initialized,
.slick-slide:first-child {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Please reproduce the issue in an online code editor and share the link.

Comment: improved grammar.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed since the tags were not closed properly.